# Facebook Login Invalid Key Hash After First Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I have added the key hash logged by this call (plus an equals sign) to the settings for my app on the Facebook developer site.

`Log.d("MyApp", FacebookSdk.getApplicationSignature(this));`

I can repeat the following steps indefinitely. Facebook login works the first time, but fails on all subsequent attempts.

Facebook App (v91.0.0.17.68)

Facebook Android SDK (v4.15.0)

1. Revoke Facebook Login at https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications
2. Login with Facebook

   - Success
3. Login with Facebook

   - Invalid key hash. The key hash KEY_HASH does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/FACEBOOK_APP_ID

---

The KEY_HASH in the error messages exactly matches one of the key hashes I have saved to the app on the Facebook developer site (at the link listed in the error message).

This only happens when the Facebook app is installed on the device. Facebook login succeeds multiple times in a row using the fallback web login.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28616205/4348328) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33023499/4348328) question that have a combined single answer of "revoke Facebook Login manually in the app before trying to log in again" which seems like a hacky workaround to me.

Why do you have to revoke Facebook Login before logging in again? With the web fallback login it just says "you've already authorized this app". I would expect the same behavior here.

Edit: This only happens with a debug build. I can login repeatedly with the Facebook app installed if I use a release build (minify disabled just to reduce the changes).

Comment: Can you try copy this hash key and paste it to devconsole of facebook

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. I have confirmed that the key hash in the error message matches one of the key hashes in the settings for my app on the Facebook developer console.

Comment: just copy this wrong haskey to your developer console.

Comment: Despite the error message saying that the key is wrong. It is already correctly saved to the app in the developer console.

Comment: Are you sure is your app public?

Comment: Yes, the app is public

Comment: look this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34961421/3313144 . I did it before and works for me.

Comment: That answer says to put the key in the developer console and to make the app public. I have already confirmed to you that I have done both of these things.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me and I had generated hash from debugkey for debugging in dev enviroment but when building it for Google Play the problem was appearing. You need to generate hash with the certificate and alias that you will sign the app for publishing in Google Play.

Edit: You need to add key hash for both debug key and release key.